# Losing data when using multithreading and networking

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

Im having an issue with multithreading and networking. This entire thing is fine if theres only 1 or 2 players. but as soon as a 3rd player is added 1 or 2 of them return a error. the errors include not being able to parse a string to a int or an index out of bounds exception. I know why both of these happen no clue how to fix it though.

The reason both of these happen is because the characters are replaced with boxes.

I think it has something to do with multiple things being sent at once? Im not positive though.

Heres how i coded it:

Every 1/20 of a second this tick method is run.

```
public void tick() {
    LinkedList<User> CopyOfUsers = null;

    synchronized(getUsers()) {
        CopyOfUsers = new LinkedList<User>(getUsers());
    }

    for(User user : CopyOfUsers) {
        try {
            user.getOutput().writeUTF("RequestingPosition");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            user.leave();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is then sent to the client.

```
while(true) {
    String message = Input.readUTF();

    String[] Data = message.split("/");

    if(Data[0].equalsIgnoreCase("RequestingPosition")) {
        if(client.getPlayer() != null) Output.writeUTF("PlayerPosition" + "/" + client.getXOffset() + "/" + client.getYOffset() + "/" + client.getPlayer().getPlayerID());
    }
}
```

Which is then sent to the corresponding user. The server has a list of users, each user has its own thread. when the client sends something to the servers its actually just sent to the corresponding user.

Which sends the data to all the clients except the one that sent it.

```
public class User implements Runnable {

public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try {
            String message = Input.readUTF();

            String[] Data = message.split("/");

            if (Data[0].equalsIgnoreCase("PlayerPosition")) {

                LinkedList<User> CopyOfUsers = null;

                synchronized(server.getUsers()) {
                    CopyOfUsers = new LinkedList<User>(server.getUsers());
                }

                for (User user : CopyOfUsers) {
                    try {
                        if(user.getPlayerID() != this.getPlayerID()) user.getOutput().writeUTF("PlayerPositions/" + Integer.parseInt(Data[1]) + "/" + Integer.parseInt(Data[2]) + "/" + Integer.parseInt(Data[3]));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then it is sent to the client with the x, y and playerid.

```
while(true) {
    String message = Input.readUTF();

    String[] Data = message.split("/");

    if(Data[0].equalsIgnoreCase("PlayerPositions")) {
        for (Player p : client.getPlayers()) {
            if (p.getPlayerID() == Integer.parseInt(Data[3])) {
                p.setXOffset(Integer.parseInt(Data[1]));
                p.setYOffset(Integer.parseInt(Data[2]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error always happens in this line:

```
if (p.getPlayerID() == Integer.parseInt(Data[3])) {
```

Is there a fix to some characters turning into boxes?

When i put a System.out.println(message) inside the while loop heres what i get.

(2 players) PlayerPositions/0/0/1

(2 players) PlayerPositions/0/0/1

(2 players) PlayerPositions/0/0/1

(2 players) PlayerPositions/0/0/1

(3 players) PlayerPositions/0/0[][]Pl

Comment: have a look what is inside `Data[3]` (debugger or println). Also check what was sent...

Comment: Data[3] prints the playerid. When i add a 3rd player it turns into a box similar to this []. Which cant be parsed to an int. It also sometime replaces the / with a [] which is why theres sometime an index out of bounds exception. the box only replaces the last few letters in entire message though.

Comment: Somehow PlayerPositions/112/106/2 turned into PlayerPositions/112/1[][]Pl

Comment: this seems like two Threads writing in the same output stream at the same time ([[][] is the length of the second string)

Comment: Oh... Thats probably it, any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: `DataInputStream` doesn't even appear in your code. What exactly is the meaning of your title?

Comment: Input.readUtf() Input is a dataInputStream

Comment: @Godzillasmash use some kind of locking    @EJP `readUTF` is a method of DataInputStream if I am not wrong...

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger And of `DataInput`, and `ObjectInputStream`, and `RandomAccessFile`, and `javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream`, ...

Comment: How would i make a locking system?

Comment: With `synchronized`. But I don't see why you would need it if every `Socket` has its own thread. I suspect something is `static` that shouldn't be `static`, or located in the main server class instead of the `Runnable` class per thread. Which again indicates that you need to post more code. What you've provided so far is insufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help! After you guys told me that it was because 2 threads were writing at the same time, I just added the messages to a queue controlled by the server and sent 1 by 1 instead of multiple at once.

Comment: @Godzillasmash I do not want to be too noisy but you should consider not sending the integers as string but as binary int (easy since using `DataInput` and `DataOutput`). Eventually the whole message should be binary (byte code instead of `"PlayerPosition") to reduce the amount of data overhead being sent over the network - obviously only if that messages are not intended for human reading.

Comment: These `synchronized` statements are worthless. If you plan to continue writing multi-threaded code, you should read a good book about that topic first.